# how to write if else conditions in Javascript string leteral?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, string-literals

```js
let temp = null

let str = `${temp} === null ? null : "${temp}" `

console.log(str)
```

my requirement is , i want to print just null with out double quotes if the temp value is null.
where as i want to print the string with double quotes if there is any value assigned to temp

### updated question:

```js
let name = null
let age = 20



let str = ` name : ${name === null ? null : name}, age : "${age}"`
`

console.log(str)
```

I have a 20 values like these to copmare and insert in the string literal ,so instead of comparing outside , am looking for a solution with in the string literal

Comment: `name:${name === null ? null : name}` is exactly same as `name:${name}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let temp = null

let str = `${temp === null ? null : `"${temp}"`}`

console.log(str)
```

Comment: i have too many values with in the string literal to validate

Comment: I don’t get it. I think above solution meets your requirement precisely. You have more requirement to add?

Comment: is there any way we can do it with in the template leteral

Comment: I’ve updated the answer as per your requirement. But still, I don’t get the point.

Comment: I guess you might find `JSON.stringify(str)` useful. It puts double quotes around string value.

Comment: awesome , now your new answer make sense

Answer (score 1):

**anti-pattern**

In another comment, you say the purpose is to inject variables into a GraphQL query. See [this example](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/react-preact/#variables) provided by formidable/urql to understand how to use variables with queries. In the light of this information, the remainder of this answer is probably not useful.

**json.stringify**

it looks like you want `JSON.stringify` -

```js
const someName = "Nancy"
const someNumber = 123.45
const someNull = null

function format(t) {
  return JSON.stringify(t)
}

console.log(`
someName: ${format(someName)}
someNumber: ${format(someNumber)}
someNull: ${format(someNull)}
`)
```

```
someName: "Nancy"
someNumber: 123.45
someNull: null
```

**tagged template**

See how it's annoying to call `format` for *each* variable? You could use a [tagged template](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#tagged_templates) to make this considerable better.

Below we can use `format` once and it will format *all* values -

```js
const myString = format`
my formatted string
with ${value1} and ${value2}
goes here
`
```

```js
const someName = "Nancy"
const someNumber = 123.45
const someNull = null

const format = (strings, ...values) =>
  values
    .flatMap((v, i) => [strings[i], JSON.stringify(v)])
    .concat([strings.at(-1)])
    .join("")
    .trim()

const myString = format`
someName: ${someName}
someNumber: ${someNumber}
someNull: ${someNull}
`

console.log(myString)
```

```
someName: "Nancy"
someNumber: 123.45
someNull: null
```

Answer (score 0):

You comparison is treated as string, try with below example:

```
let temp = 'a'

let str = `${temp === null ? "null" : temp}`

console.log(str)
```

Comment: not working as per your example 
let name = "hello"
let age = 20



let str = ` name : ${name === null ? null : name}, age : "${age}"`

console.log(str)

Answer (score 0):

The questions don't make sense.  If you're printing name and age then that's not coming off a single string, it's maybe multiple strings stored in an object and/or array.  20 references?  Passed in separately?  It seems a bit odd.

The difference is, if it's coming out of an object or an array, the references will be different.  The code will be different.

Just copy and paste the whole assignment, make things easier.

==

If the code really IS supposed to be single variables at a time:

```js
let name = null;
let age = 20;

let str = ` name : "${name === null ? null : name}", age : "${age}"``;

console.log(str);
```

You put " " around the ${}, same as you did for age.

Comment: the conversion am doing here for a graphQL query , that expects eiither double quoted string or null. so the accepted answer is the right way to do it

Comment: @sravanganji no, if you are passing variables to a graphql query, you should not be doing it this way. See [this example](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/basics/react-preact/#variables) from urql.